# Download Photosphere images

Tags: photos, downloading

I have [Google Cardboard](https://cardboard.withgoogle.com/) which works great with Photosphere. I've created a few of my own, but I'd really like to get some spectacular images (e.g. Times Square, Grand Canyon etc) to install on my phone to demonstrate to people.

I have found Photosphere images online, but they are only viewable online - is there a way to download these images** so they can be viewed as photosphere images on my Android phone ?

** Assuming of course that appropriate license allows me to download a copy.

Answer (score 1):

As photosphere pictures are just "normal" jpg-files, you just have to download the photosphere image. If you use android you can view photosphere images with the google+ app. There is no real download-button, but you can use the share button and then send the picture to your email-adress for example. The standard android gallery viewer will open the picture like every photosphere picture you make with your mobile by yourself.

Comment: Google+ has the option "Download" on most images, in Chrome you can long press the picture and "Save" it. They're not necessarily JPG format either.

Comment: If you donwload the image with long press, make shure that you don't download the thumbnail preview of the panorama. The panorama-informations are saved in the XMP metatag of the jpg file. Detailed information [here](https://chris.orr.me.uk/photo-sphere-formats-metadata/)... What else format than jpg did you see, Ross?

Comment: Sorry, that got cut off as I had to run to a meeting. If you are downloading it online it **might** be saved as any format. I have seen them online in png etc, but yes the device does save them as JPG generally. I was more thinking "don't go online looking for only jpg files." Good point on the thumbnail, but that's up to the user really!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add " PANO_ " without the quotes to the front of the jpeg name, PANO_ abc.jpg for instance. Then you also have to add metadata. You can do that here. http://photo-sphere.appspot.com/.  This is a google page which you upload your image and then add metadata in respect of place. Then you download the image again and put it in the 360 Panoramas folder of your phone. Sorted.